# Express route file upload via Busboy and HTML form hangs indefinitely, produces no output

Tags: javascript, express, upload

I'm trying to perform `multipart/form-data` file upload on a file that I need to provide as the binary body for a put request, but I can't seem to get any indication the file upload is working. To my knowledge, this should be doable without using any client-side javascript but I'm beginning to question that assumption. Ideally I'd like to stream the content from the browser to the API without it being written to disk, but if writing to disk simplifies the code I am open to that too. Thanks ahead of time. -- Brian

**HTML:**

```
<h3><i class="fas fa-upload fa-fw"></i>File Upload</h3>
<form action="/getViewingSession" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="12u">
            <div class="hidden"><input type="text" name="type" value="upload"></div>
            <div class="field"><input type="file" name="upload" required></div>
            <p><sub></sub></p>
        </div>
        <div class="12u">
            <input type="submit" value="Next" class="float-right" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Express Route:**

```
this.app.post("/getViewingSession", function(request, response) {
    let busboy = new Busboy({ headers: request.headers });

    busboy.on("file", function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log("File [" + fieldname + "]: filename: " + filename);

        file.on("data", function(data) {
            console.log("File [" + fieldname + "] got " + data.length + " bytes");
        });

        file.on("end", function() {
            console.log("File [" + fieldname + "] Finished");
        });
    });

    busboy.on("finish", function() {                            
        response.end();

        serverRequest.post({
            "url": request.protocol + "://localhost:" + config.get("port") + "/pas/ViewingSession",
            "json": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "upload",
                    "displayName": "displayName"
                }
            }
        }, function(error, httpResponse, body) {
            let viewingSessionId = body["viewingSessionId"];

            serverRequest.put({
                "url": request.protocol + "://localhost:" + config.get("port") + "/pas/ViewingSession/u" + viewingSessionId + "/SourceFile",
                // Send the file here (request.pipe(busboy)?)
            }, function(error, httpResponse, body) {
                response.redirect("viewer?viewingSessionId=" + body["viewingSessionId"]);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**Error Message:**

```
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
const busboy = new Busboy({ "headers": request.headers, "limits": { "files": 1, "fileSize": 100 * 1024 * 1024 } });

let file;
let hostingType;

busboy.on("file", function(fieldName, fileStream, fileName, encoding, mimeType) {
    const bufferArray = [];

    fileStream.on("data", function(data) {
        bufferArray.push(data);
    });

    fileStream.on("end", function() {
        file = Buffer.concat(bufferArray);
    });
});

busboy.on("field", function(fieldName, value, fieldNameTruncated, valueTruncated, encoding, mimeType) {
    if (fieldName === "hostingType") {
        hostingType = value;
    }
});

busboy.on("finish", function() {
    requestJs.post({
        "url": request.protocol + "://localhost:" + config.get("port") + "/" + hostingType + "-hosted/ViewingSession",
        "json": {
            "source": {
                "type": "upload",
                "displayName": "upload"
            }
        }
    }, function(error, httpResponse, body) {
        const viewingSessionId = body["viewingSessionId"];

        requestJs.put({
            "url": request.protocol + "://localhost:" + config.get("port") + "/" + hostingType + "-hosted/ViewingSession/u" + viewingSessionId + "/SourceFile",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                "Accusoft-Secret": "mysecretkey"
            },
            "body": file
        }, function(error, httpResponse, body) {
            response.redirect("viewer?hostingType=" + hostingType + "&viewingSessionId=" + viewingSessionId);
        });
    });
});

request.pipe(busboy);
```